# How to describe the transformation that changes French flag to Russian flag?

Tags: group-theory, geometry

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&f=ob&i=Russia%2C%20France%20flags

I presume it can be described two group operators, but I'm not sure how to come up with the formal description.  I know one of them must be the element of the 2-d rotation group SO(2) that rotate the surface counterclockwise for $\pi/2$, and the other is to flip the white and the blue bends of the French flag -- what group element is it?  How does the notation representing this look like?

Answer (score 3):

It's also a different shade of blue.  But if you disregard that, you might consider the flags as divided into $9$ regions in a $3 \times 3$ grid, and then there are permutations of the $9$ regions that will do it.

Comment: The three-bends picture is more intuitive, why $3 \times 4$ grid picture?

Comment: Also the reds are of a different kinds.